# Modeling Question

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have the following two models:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :photoalbums
end

class PhotoAlbum < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :space
end
```

routes.rb:

```
resources :projects do
  resources :photo_albums
end
```

What I'm trying to do in the Controller is get a list of all the project's photoalbums:

```
class PhotoAlbumsController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @photoalbums = @project.photoalbums.all
  end
end
```

But I'm getting the following error?

```
uninitialized constant Project::Photoalbum
```

Answer (score 2):

Replace all occurrences of `photoalbum` with `photo_album`.

Rails is smart and maps your `photo_album` to `PhotoAlbum` (note the two caps). It only capitalises at the beginning of a string or after an underscore. As you've seen, `photoalbum` corresponds to `Photoalbum` (one cap), which does not exist in your application.

Answer (score 1):

Try `has_many :photo_albums`, and then `@photo_albums = @project.photo_albums`

Comment: Accept and rate the answer if it helped you.